# How to catch MPMoviePlayerController rotation event?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

i've added this code in my ViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; 
} 
return YES;
}
```

So after rotation my player plays video in fullscreen mode. I need to catch rotation event in playerController (OrientationPortrait) to setFullScreen:NO.
How can I do this?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting of orientation of moviePlayerController should not be handled in this function.

Add a notifier in the viewWillAppear function

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];}
```

---

The orientation change notifies this function

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
[self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];}
```

---

which in-turn calls this function where the moviePlayerController frame is orientation is handled

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
{ 
    [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];    
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
    [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; 
}}
```

---

in viewDidDisappear remove the notification

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's worked, but after rotation I've this problem. http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/4929/20514487.png

Comment: The position of the navigation bar is changing in portrait mode. Set the top value of the navigation bar as 20.0 when you com back to the portrait mode. Hope this solves you problem.

Comment: You can simplify the `-adjustViewsForOrientation:` method by using the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait()` and `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()` macros.